# WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns machine name rather than windows user name

Tags: wcf, web-services, ws-security, windows-identity

I am calling a web service application (.asmx) running in a virtual directory on an IIS 7.5 (for development purposes I only have IIS 5.1 but am hoping for some help anyway). Calling my ws when running from within VS2010 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns domain\windows user but when I call it through the virtual directory I get machine name\ASPNET.

For some reason  is not allowed in the web.config on the final environment. The virtual directory has Integrated Windows authentication only.

Can anyone shed some light on how to get the current users windows username under the circumstances described?

Thanks in advance...

./CJ

Answer (score 0):

Was allowed to use impersonation after all... now it all works